# Can I use Azure AD B2c as secondary authentication provider in asp.net core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

There are many scenarios where there is Azure ad b2c is main authentication provider and there are additional authentication provider configured to work with it. for e.g Google, Facebook, etc. I have configured login with Google and Login with Facebook with Azure AD b2c. But in this case I need to add button like Login with B2c.

I have asp.net core website already configured with one OpenId based authentication provider (for e.g let's say Salesforce) Now I want to configure additional authentication provider that is Azure AD B2c. What configuration do I need to do b2c side and how to add additional authentication provider asp.net core web application side?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Third-party identity verification and proofing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview#third-party-identity-verification-and-proofing).

Azure's ISV partner network extends it's solution capabilities to help you build seamless end-user experiences. With Azure AD B2C, you can integrate with ISV partners to enable multi-factor authentication methods, enable Secure Customer Authentication (SCA), perform Role-Based Access Control, and combat fraud through identity verification and proofing. For more information about this, you can visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/partner-gallery) link.

Comment: If I am not getting you wrong this answer is not relevant to my requirement. Let me be more clear. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-overview#external-identity-providers) explained that I can integrate external Identity provider with B2c. So here B2c is primary authentication provider and Google, Facebook etc are secondary authentication provider. But in my case I have reverse requirement. I have already configured Salesforce authentication as primary authentication provider and I want to add B2c as secondary authentication provider.

Comment: Would external identity provider federation help your case? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-overview
I don't think there is any other direct way.

Comment: Pls note that there is no concept of primary or secondary authentication. User can either login using local acct using B2C or social acct using social idp.

Comment: I got it, but I need to allow user to login with local acct using B2c or as social acct using another B2c tenant. is that possible? (Please note I am talking two different B2c tenant)

Comment: It is possible, but not on same page, it will require different Login pages since the B2C tenants are different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on Azure AD specifics, but there is an industry standard for Open Id Connect federation.

The key goal is to integrate external providers with no extra cost to your apps. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) explains the architecture.

So while this may not be a complete answer, I hope it helps you to clarify what you want. It is easy to get lost in vendor specific marketing articles if not careful.